# AWS Lambdas and API Gateway Stages

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

What happens when you deploy a stage in the AWS API Gateway and then update your Lambda? Is the Lambda versioned?

Let's say I have a lambda `charlie` and I upload it (version 1) then deploy a API Gateway stage, `dev`. Then I make an update to `charlie` (version 2) and deploy another stage (`prod`)?

- Are stage `dev` and stage `prod` running the same Lambda?
- Or is `dev` running `version 1` of charlie & `prod` running `version 2`?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/

Comment: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-stages.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-stages.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What happens when you deploy a stage in the AWS API Gateway and then
>   update your Lambda? Is the Lambda versioned?

Lambdas are versioned if you follow [AWS Lambda Versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-intro.html) and you  publish a version by either a) publishing a version explicitly, or b) [publishing a version at the time you create or update a Lambda function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-intro.html#versioning-intro-publish-versionhttp://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-intro.html#versioning-intro-publish-version)

If you are using [API Gateway stage variables](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/), then you can call different Lambda versions using stage variables and Lambda version aliases.

> Are stage dev and stage prod running the same Lambda?

Yes. Unless you publish and manage Lambda versions.

> Or is dev running version 1 of charlie & prod running version 2?

No. As mentioned above, you need to use stage variables and aliases.

Comment: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-stages.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-stages.html)